# How to specify table.type in Storybook ArgTypes

Tags: reactjs, storybook

From the official document of [Argtypes](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes), it shows the types can be shown in format `"small"|"medium"|"large"` in the following ArgsTable example [image: example], however there is no details about how to define `table.type` to make it looks like this. Currently I'm using

```
table: 
{
  type: { summary: ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'] },
},
```

And it shows `type1, type2, type3, type4` in the storybook, which is not ideal.
Does anyone know how to implement it as the way it shows in the example?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was just put all options in a single string and delimited it with the the pipe symbol

```
table: 
{
  type: { summary: 'type1 | type2 | type3 | type4' },
}
```